# Do I have to include "SELECT @@RowCount" if I have more than one SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rowcount

I know that, if I execute a single SQL statement that UPDATEs or DELETEs some data, that it will return the *number of rows affected.*

But if I have multiple SQL statements in a sql script, and I want to know the number of rows affected *from the last statement executed,* will it still return that automatically, or do I need a

```
SELECT @@RowCount
```

at the end of the script?

The code in question is not a Stored Procedure.  Rather, it is a parameterized SQL script stored in an arbitrary location, executed using the `ExecuteStoreCommand` function in Entity Framework, as in:

```
var numberOfRowsAffected = context.ExecuteStoreCommand<int>(mySqlScript, parameters);
```

Comment: I have tried numerous Googles, and they all return information about how `@@RowCount` works.  None of them say if `SELECT @@RowCount` is implied.

Comment: Seems like you could run it one way then the other and see what the results are... is it more complicated than that?  Might be missing something, but that's what I'd do.

Comment: It kinda is.  The setup is rather complicated, and it would be nice if I had a reference.

Comment: I think what you're after, and it's a reasonable question, is to get clarity on whether an observed behavior is actually documented behavior and can be relied on.  Am I right?.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder: Now you've got it.

Comment: I think it depends if you need to make your query fit in with Entity Framework's incorrect assumptions. This question is really about gaming EF to work rather than about TSQL in general. The best answer, in the long run, might be don't use EF but I suspect that is not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: If you include the statement `SET NOCOUNT ON;` before any query then you can expect no row count messages to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the [`NOCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms189837.aspx) setting when executing your quer(y/ies).

If `NOCOUNT` is `ON` then no `DONE_IN_PROC` messages will NOT be returned.

If `NOCOUNT` is `OFF`, the default setting, then `DONE_IN_PROC` messages will be returned, (eg. counts).

Both of these situations are different to executing,

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

which will return a result set with a single scalar value, different from a DONE_IN_PROC message. This will occur, regardless of the setting of `NOCOUNT`.

I believe that `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` is sometimes used to make Entity Framework "play" with more complex TSQL statements because EF both requires

1. Requires a count for post validation
2. And will accept a scalar number result set as a substitute for a `DONE_IN_PROC` message.

Its important that `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;` is executed immediately after the last query statement because many statements will reset `@@ROWCOUNT` and therefore yield an unexpected result.

Comment: **tl;dr:** Don't confuse anyone by attempting to assert implied behavior.  Make it explicit by always including `SELECT @@RowCount` in your script (if that is the intent).

Answer (score 0):

Just to be specific on answer part, you would need to add SELECT @@RowCount to return number of rows affected by last statement.

I think confusion might be due to rows returned in SSMS window while executing query.By default SSMS shows number of rows returned for all sql statements but it returns affected rows as message not a *dataset*.

Comment: To be clear, if there's just one INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement in the script, it will always return the number of rows affected in my `numberOfRowsAffected` variable, as illustrated above in my question, even if I do not include a `SELECT @@RowCount`.  The question here is, does that still hold for multiple statements?  Does it return `@@RowCount` for the last executed statement?

Comment: @@RowCount will return row count for last executed statement. It will not hold results for multiple statements. If you want to implement such scenario you can declare variable in sql script and then bump up this variable with @@RowCount after every DML statement.

Comment: You're not getting my question.  I want to know if I can safely **omit** `SELECT @@RowCount` for scripts having multiple INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements, what the resulting behavior will be, and if that behavior (whatever it is) can be relied upon.

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood your question. It's safe to omit SELECT @@RowCount after any DML statement. It's not going have any impact on your functionality.

Comment: Yes, but will it reliably return the number of rows affected from the last DML statement?

Comment: Yes,it will reliably return the number of rows affected by last statement.

Answer (score -1):

@@ROWCOUNT will automatically return number of rows effected by the last statement.

Please find the msdn link here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Comment: If I omit @@RowCount, will it still return the number of rows affected **from the last insert or update?**

Comment: No, we have to use @@rowcount if we want to know number of affected rows from the last statement.